# User enter a date string ('year' or 'month') and it applies to date.userinputdate

Tags: python, datetime, variables, global-variables, local-variables

I have

```
term = input("Enter a variable name")  #choose the term (i.e.,day,week,month)
```

and in my code there is a section as below

```
date.term
```

I like users can input 'month' or 'year' and the code can function as

```
date.month
```

or

```
date.year
```

How can I do this.
Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: What is `date`: a variable, function, package, etc.?

Comment: Have you tried `if` statements? https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1):

Use `if` statements to read the user input:

```py
if term == 'day':
   # something using date.day
elif term == 'month':
   # something using date.month
elif term == 'year':
   # something using date.year
else:
   print(f'Invalid term: "{term}"')
```

Alternatively, if you trust the user input, you could use `exec()`:

```py
exec(f'print("date.{term}")')
```